# How to display either image (img) or pdf (iframe)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf, iframe

Dynamic links I display on my page (rest) may result in jpeg, tif or pdf file in the response.

I tried to do it like this (the images part works fine):

```
fetchContent(uri){
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",            
        url: uri,

        success: function(output, status, xhr) {
            var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");

            if(contentType === "image/jpeg" || contentType === "image/tiff"){

                // IMG: get parent div 'container'
                var $container = $('#container', top.frames["content"].document);
                var img = new Image();

                $(img)
                    .load(function(){
                        // initially hide
                        $(this).hide();
                        $(this).attr('id', 'imgId');

                        // parent div:
                        $container
                            // remove previous image
                            .empty()
                            // add this image
                            .append(this);

                        // fade in image effect
                        $(this).fadeIn();

                    })

                    // set the src attribute of the new image to our image
                    .attr('src', uri);

            }else if(contentType === "application/pdf"){
                // PDF: get parent div 'main'
                var $main = $('#main', top.frames["content"].document);

                $main.empty();
                $main.append("<iframe id='contentIFrame' name='contentIFrame' src='" + uri +
                "' width='100%' style='height:100%'></iframe>");
            }
        },
        complete: function(output){
            $('#navigation-block').append(output);
        },

        error: function(output) {
            $('#navigation-block').append(output);
        }
    });
}
```

The PDF part doesn't work.

How do I sort that out?

BTW, I control both REST server side and jQuery side so I added correct content-type in REST response header.

I checked out PDF.js and would have used it, but my client unfortunately uses IE8.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly happens (or doesn't happen) when it's a PDF? Does your iFrame show, you can test it with just "hello" in it. Do PDF files open in your browser naturally, say from other site? Because your PDFs can either open in-page with your reader or in the stand-alone reader application.

Comment: Sorry about the incomplete post, but I'm not exactly sure what happens cuz' the success callback never gets called. When I debug jQuery I see that it results in some kind of "no transport" error. I don't exactly know how to step-into (set breakpoint) inside ajax request so that I can see what's going on? The whole ajax block is stepped over. Is there some kind of trick for this?

Comment: It works! Maybe it was cross-domain problem. For testing purposes this patient (me) used PDF URL from some random web site. After I added pdf support in my REST service it started working. <br>Thanks anyway.

Comment: try pdf object: http://pdfobject.com/examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final solution to the problem of not knowing in advance what a link is going to return (jpeg, tif or pdf):

```
function fetchImage(uri, $activeLink){
    // show loader div
    var $loadingStatus = $('#loadingStatus', top.frames["content"].document);
    $loadingStatus.fadeIn();

    // remember (select) the link that has just been activated
    $("#navigation-block>ul>li>a.zactive").removeClass("zactive");
    $($activeLink).addClass('zactive');


    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",            
        url: uri,

        success: function(output, status, xhr) {
            // for images use main parent div 'main-img'
            var $mainImg = $('#main-img', top.frames["content"].document);
            // for pdf use parent div 'main-pdf'
            var $mainPdf = $('#main-pdf', top.frames["content"].document);

            // REST service will always return correct content-type
            var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");

            if(contentType === "image/jpeg" || contentType === "image/tiff"){

                // for images we also need child div 'container'
                var $container = $('#container', top.frames["content"].document);
                var img = new Image();

                $(img)
                    .load(function(){
                        // default: hide image
                        $(this).hide();
                        $(this).attr('id', 'imgId');

                        // img parent div:
                        $container
                            // remove previous img 
                            .empty() 
                            // insert this img 
                            .append(this); 

                        // hide pdf div and show img div
                        $($mainPdf).hide();
                        $($mainImg).show();

                        // fade in image 
                        $(this).fadeIn();

                        // remove loader div
                        $loadingStatus.stop(true, true).fadeOut();
                    })

                    // set the src attribute of the new image to this uri
                    .attr('src', uri);

            }else if(contentType === "application/pdf"){

                $mainPdf.empty(); // so I don't have to check whether iframe is already there
                $mainPdf.append("<iframe id='contentIFrame' name='contentIFrame' src='" + uri +
                "' width='100%' style='height:100%'></iframe>");

                // hide img div and show pdf div
                $($mainImg).hide();
                $($mainPdf).show();
            }
        },

        error: function(output) {
            alert("error " + output);
        }
    });
}
```